# How do I set up a multivariate hierarchical multiple linear regression in R?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis, nested-data

I have two continuous DVs (measurements taken on individual fish), one continuous individual level IV (fish's size), and two site-level IVs (PC1 and PC4). Sites are either take or no take. There are 13 sites and 178 observations. This is what some of that data looks like

```
Site  Status DV1  DV2  Size  PC1   PC4
A     Take   -12   5    23    2     35
A     Take   -13   3    22    2     35
A     Take   -11   4    18    2     35
B     NoTake -10   5    15    7     44
B     NoTake -12   5    15    7     44
B     NoTake -13   4    23    7     44
```

The first thing I did was set up a model with no predictors to see if I needed both site and status.
Code:

```
Y<-cbind(mydata$DV1, mydata$DV2)
model1<-lmer(Y ~ 1 + (1 | Status/Site), data=mydata)
```

Output:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: Y ~ 1 + (1 | Status/Site) 
   Data: mydata 
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 353.4 366.1 -172.7    342.9   345.4
Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Site:Status (Intercept) 0.14571  0.38172 
 Status      (Intercept) 0.00000  0.00000 
 Residual                0.35205  0.59334 
Number of obs: 178, groups: Site:Status, 13; Status, 2

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) -13.4616     0.1149  -117.1
```

From this I see that 0.14571/(0.14571+0.35205), or 29% of the total variance is due to Site, whereas 0% is attributed to Status. Am I interpreting this correctly? I dropped Status from the model, and proceeded to add my IVs. Next, I added only the individual level predictor, allowing for varying slopes and intercepts:

```
model2<-lmer(Y ~ TL + (1 | Site), data=mydata)
model3<-lmer(Y ~ TL + (1 + TL | Site), data=mydata)
anova (model2, model3)
```

Output of model1:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: Y ~ TL + (1 | Site) 
   Data: mydata 
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 320.7 333.5 -156.4    304.1   312.7
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Site     (Intercept) 0.21014  0.45842 
 Residual             0.27351  0.52298 
Number of obs: 178, groups: Site, 13

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) -15.60402    0.34472  -45.27
TL            0.10577    0.01571    6.73

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
   (Intr)
TL -0.922
```

From this I see that TL is an important predictor and in comparing both models....

```
Data: mydata
Models:
model2: Y ~ TL + (1 | Site)
model3: Y ~ TL + (1 + TL | Site)
       Df    AIC    BIC  logLik  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
model2  4 312.06 324.79 -152.03                         
model3  6 313.82 332.91 -150.91 2.2441      2     0.3256
```

...it doesn't look like slopes are different among sites. I eliminated this from the following models. Next, I added my group level predictors, PC1 and PC4. Models:

```
model4<-lmer(Y ~ TL + PC1 + (1 | Site), data=mydata)
model5<-lmer(Y ~ TL + PC4 + (1 | Site), data=mydata)
model6<-lmer(Y ~ TL + PC4 + PC1 +(1 | Site), data=mydata)
```

And to compare those:

```
Data: mydata
Models:
model4: Y ~ TL + PC1 + (1 | Site)
model5: Y ~ TL + PC4 + (1 | Site)
model6: Y ~ TL + PC4 + PC1 + (1 | Site)
       Df    AIC    BIC  logLik Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
model4  5 311.59 327.50 -150.79                        
model5  5 314.13 330.04 -152.06 0.000      0      1.000
model6  6 313.72 332.81 -150.86 2.404      1      0.121
```

Summary of Model 4:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
Formula: Y ~ TL + PC1 + (1 | Site) 
   Data: mydata 
   AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 323.3 339.2 -156.7    301.6   313.3
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Site     (Intercept) 0.18655  0.43192 
 Residual             0.27342  0.52290 
Number of obs: 178, groups: Site, 13

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) -15.63657    0.34288  -45.60
TL            0.10724    0.01574    6.81
PC1          -0.14471    0.09297   -1.56

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr) TL    
TL  -0.930       
PC1  0.080 -0.080
```

My questions are just very generally if I have set this up correctly. I have not seen any examples of multivariate hierarchical models. I have set up models with my DV's separately as well and when I do that, the equivalent of model 6 (PC1+PC4) comes out on top. Additionally, how would I visualize bivariate data in a hierarchical way?

Also, I don't know how to interpret the "Correlation of Fixed Effects" in the output of the model. I am not sure what this means. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: It is possible that you have not set up the model correctly. If I am correct, I think your model is only estimating the parameters for one of the DVs. What estimates do you get when you just run the DV2? Are they the same as for this "multivariate" version? Maybe the following link helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831243/multivariate-linear-mixed-model-in-lme4

Comment: Where does TL come from? What is its relation to "individual level predictors"?